# What programs on Linux can recover a Windows password from another part of the system?

Tags: linux, usb, password-recovery

I am going to create a portable Linux on an 8gig USB drive, and I was wondering if there was a password recovery tool within Linux to recover passwords from Windows/Mac(at least Windows).

I know there are plenty of stand alone USB start up programs for this, but I would like to find one that is a package for Linux already.  I'd like to have a suite of tools plus a portable operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian/Ubuntu should have deb package for [chntpw](http://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/chntpw/download) or you can just build the utility from [source](http://www.pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/editor.html).

Comment: Note that `chntpw` will not *recover* the existing (Windows) passwords, it merely allows you to *overwrite* them with new ones. This is an important distinction, as 1) encrypted user profiles are not crackable this way (which is quite the point of using them), and 2) ability to actually recover the original password would indicate exceptionally poor security of the OS.